# PHPMailer:send HTML format

Tags: php, html, format, phpmailer

I need to use PHPMailer to send emails with html format,but my email has hundreds of lines with many html tags and inline css,even there are some php code in it.it look like this:

```
$message=<<<str
　　　　//some html code
   　　hello {$name}.   //$name is a php variable
  　　//come html code
  　　//hunderd of lines
str;
```

now i think tee meesage that to be sent is too large,is there clean way to do this?
  or I want to know  how you will send a html format email with so large body?
  sorry for my bad englis!thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an example

```
 $message = '<html><body><div style="background-color:#FFFFFF; padding:15px 15px 40px 65px;width:490px;margin:0 auto">';

 $message .= '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin-bottom:7px;"><tbody style="color:#000000;">';

 $message .= '<tr><td width="170"><label style="display:block;padding:5px 0 10px 0;width:170px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px">Name :</label></td><td width="277" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px">&nbsp;&nbsp;'. $name.'</td></tr>';
```

In the end

```
$mail->MsgHTML($message);
```

Comment: if this way,there  are also hundreds of lines!

Answer (score 0):

Is text...so in order to be "too large" ... it would need to have more than 1 mill lines... (from space the occupied point of view).

In order to send an email in the html format just add this headers to your existing ones:

```
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 \r\n";
```

And store all your lines into a variable. (add the php variables using string concatenation or something similar)

Comment: Thank you! it seems only can do it this way!